# How can I obtain access results from my country?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am a developer of the Japanese website, and I am using PageSpeed Insights.

The website is Multilingual site.
For example, if you are accessing from the US, you redirect to the US version site.

I want to obtain access results from my country, but the screen capture of results seems to the US version site.

Previous versions of PageSpeed Insights offered access results from my country.

How can I obtain access results from Japan?

Thanks